# Get IPv6 to work

Tags: linux, networking, debian, routing, ipv6

I'm trying to get IPv6 to work.
My host provied me the following informations:
IPv6 network: `2a03:4000:2:483::/64`
IPv6 gateway: `fe80::1`

My `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

#IPV6 static configuration
iface eth0 inet6 static
pre-up modprobe ipv6
address 2a03:4000:2:483::2
netmask 64
gateway fe80::1
# END IPV6 configuration
```

And `ifconfig` outputs the following:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:7e:5a:c2:b4
          inet addr:46.38.236.169  Bcast:46.38.239.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:7eff:fe5a:c2b4/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2a03:4000:2:483::2/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:173542 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27863 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:10582552 (10.0 MiB)  TX bytes:1658598 (1.5 MiB)
```

`ip -6 route show` outputs:

```
default via fe80::1 dev eth0  metric 1024
```

And `route -6`:

```
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
2a03:4000:2:483::/64           ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
::/0                           fe80::1                    UG   1024 0     0 eth0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1    50 lo
::1/128                        ::                         Un   0   1    25 lo
2a03:4000:2:483::2/128         ::                         Un   0   1    15 lo
fe80::5054:7eff:fe5a:c2b4/128  ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1    50 lo
```

`ping6 ipv6.google.com` results in

```
PING ipv6.google.com(muc03s08-in-x04.1e100.net) 56 data bytes
From 2a03:4000:2:483::2 icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From 2a03:4000:2:483::2 icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From 2a03:4000:2:483::2 icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
--- ipv6.google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2999ms
```

The server is running `Debian 3.2.51-1`. I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: try ping6 ipv6.google.com%eth0 sometimes being explicit helps. Aside from that this GW address fe80::1 seems a bit strange. this range has been set aside for link local addresses and should not be used for GW stuff.

Comment: @zeridon: link-local addresses are very often used for gateways. That is one of its purposes. Take a look at a machine that got its default GW from a Router Advertisement. It will be a link-local address, and it will work just fine.

Comment: @Kimmax: Check your firewall settings. I wouldn't be surprised if your (default?) firewall is blocking IPv6 traffic. Note that for IPv6 you have to use `ip6tables` instead of `iptables`

Comment: link-local addresses are fine for gateways, but you still need to confirm that you have the right address for the gateway.  Where is the router in all this?

Comment: I set up the ip6tables with help of this doc: http://madduck.net/docs/ipv6/ Is this right?

Comment: The gateway address does indeed look wrong. Try pinging it directly: `ping6 fe80::1%eth0`